# Repair damaged videos that tend to have infinite times

Tags: gratis, open-source, video, video-recording, repair

On `Android` 10 Samsung Mobile I used  a camera app with `API 2` enabled ( ? ) . This caused corrupt  video recordings. In most such corrupt videos I can see that the time length is infinite even though the video itself is 2 mins / 10mb.  I can see that [this website fix video](https://fix.video/#recentuploads) can repair it. I tried other offline tools like stellar , EaseUS  etc none could fix it even after I provided them a template but this can do it without template. I also tried `ffmpeg` and `untrunc` on Linux - no use. Is there an open source or free tool  same capability as fix.video one but or command line ops that do what it does ?  esp for Linux